# Is SLF4jJ 1.8.0-alpha2 compatible with Log4j 2.8.2

Tags: java, slf4j, log4j2

I have configured in a project SLF4J with LOG4J2.

When I try to combine the current latest versions of them (SLF4J 1.8.0-alpha2 and LOG4J 2.8.2) I get this message when I log something:

```
SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
SLF4J: Class path contains SLF4J bindings targeting slf4j-api versions prior to 1.8.
SLF4J: Ignoring binding found at [jar:file:/home/castros/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.8.2/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.8.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#ignoredBindings for an explanation.
```

However, if I try with a lowest version of SLF4J (1.7.24) it works as expected.

I am interested in using SLF4J 1.8.0-alpha2 since it claims to be Java 9 ready.

This is an extract of the configuration of my POM:

```
     <properties>
        <!-- This one does not work -->
        <slf4j.version>1.8.0-alpha2</slf4j.version>
        <!-- This one works -->
        <!--<slf4j.version>1.7.24</slf4j.version>-->
        <log4j2.version>2.8.2</log4j2.version>
    </properties>
    </dependencies>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
                <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
                <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
                <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.lmax</groupId>
                <artifactId>disruptor</artifactId>
                <version>${disruptor.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
                <version>${jackson-dataformat-yaml.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I verified that no other SLF4J bindings and no other version of SLF4JAPI lower than 1.8 are in the classpath.

Comment: It appears the API the slf4j implementations must adhere to has changed.   Did you see http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#ignoredBindings for an explanation?

Comment: yes, I read that page. See the last line of my question. Thanks!