# Is slf4j 2.0.0-alpha7 compatible with log4j 2.17.2?

Tags: log4j, slf4j

My problem is extremely similar to the one outlined in this post (it is unanswered): [Is SLF4jJ 1.8.0-alpha2 compatible with Log4j 2.8.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45729193/is-slf4jj-1-8-0-alpha2-compatible-with-log4j-2-8-2).

I am trying to upgrade from slf4j 1.7.36 to 2.0.0-alpha7.

Currently I have this in my POM:

```
<!-- https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/maven-artifacts.html -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.2</version>
        </dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.36</version>
    </dependency>
<!--  https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/maven-artifacts.html -->  
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
       <version>2
```

.17.2

This works as intended.

Every time that I try to change slf4j to 2.0.0-alpha7 I get the following error:

SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
SLF4J: Class path contains SLF4J bindings targeting slf4j-api versions prior to 1.8.

Does anyone know what causes this?

Comment: Question is now doubly relevant, as slf4j 2.0.0 (release) is available, the log4j2 docs talk extensively about "slf4j 1.8.x" as if that is a real thing and not in deprecated beta, and none of it (apparently) works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is at the moment no SLF4J 2.x binding for Log4j2.

The main reason is that SLF4J 2.x is in its **alpha** stage and might still have backward incompatible changes without previous notice. There is a branch ([`slf4j-2.0`](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/tree/slf4j-2.0)) of Log4j2's repository that contains a preliminary version of a `log4j-slf4j2-impl`, but I wouldn't count on it being merged before SLF4J 2.0 reaches a **beta** stage at least.

**Edit:** The `log4j-slf4j2-impl` module is available from version `2.19.0`.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer! I tried 1.8.0-beta4, but I am still having the same error. Is it also the case for 1.8x?

Comment: There is a [`log4j-slf4j18-impl`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-slf4j18-impl) module that supports SLF4J 1.8, although the  SLF4J 1.8.x series has been discontinued.

Comment: Would it be advisable to jump to that or stay with 1.7.36 until 2 comes out? Essentially, I am wondering what is meant by discontinued.

Comment: Personally I would switch to Log4j 2.x API, which has all the features SLF4J 2.x has, but it is stable.